# Generating function for Schur polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, generating-functions, schur-functions

Consider  the generating function
$$
G_n(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n, t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n) =\sum_{\lambda}s_{\lambda}(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n) t_1^{\lambda_1}t_2^{\lambda_2} \cdots t_n^{\lambda_n},
$$
where the sum is over all partitions $\lambda=(\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\ldots, \lambda_n)$ and $s_\lambda$ is a Schur polynomial.

For small $n$ such generating function  is easy to find, for example for $n=2$ by direct calculation we have
$$
G_2(x_1,x_2, t_1,t_2)=\sum_{\lambda}s_{\lambda}(x_1,x_2) t_1^{\lambda_1}t_2^{\lambda_2}=\frac{1}{(1-x_1 t_1)(1-x_2 t_1)(1-x_1 x_2 t_1 t_2)}.
$$
If we put $t_1=t_2=1$ then  we come to well-known Littlewood identity

$$
\sum_{\lambda}s_{\lambda}(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{(1-x_1)(1-x_2)(1-x_1 x_2)}.
$$

**Question.** Is there any close expression for the generating function $G_n$ for arbitrary $n?$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is done in my paper [The character generator of SU(*n*)](https://klein.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/44.pdf). I believe there was an essentially the same previous MO question, but I am unable to find it.

Comment: In case the link to the PDF file is broken, the DOI is (almost certainly) https://doi.org/10.1063/1.524687

Comment: @Richard Stanley. Thank you for the answer!